# GIMP: Is there a scrolling image filter?

Tags: gimp

Is there a filter which creates a "scrolling" animation of an image, e.g. shifts the image to the right by so many pixels and wraps pixels that go off the right edge back to the left. I would like the filter to repeat this so that in the end there is a nice scrolling effect when played back via Filter/Animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link in xenoid's answer does not wrap.
However, I just recently wrote (I meant like 5 minutes ago) one that wraps layer and scrolls only the active/selected layer.
https://gimplearn.net/viewtopic.php?desc=Scrolling-and-Wraps-layer-animation-Script-for-GIMP&f=3&t=414

Comment: Thanks. On Ubuntu in `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/` there is no plug ins folder... why should I put the `.py` file ?

Comment: try  in /home/<userName>/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.gimplearn.net/viewtopic.php?desc=Scrolling-Animation-Logo-Script-for-GIMP&f=3&t=386

At worst use a transparent layer for the layers you don't need. But the author is likely willing to write a single-layer version.

Comment: Ok I just did `locate *.py | grep gimp` and think I found the right plug ins folder. Hmm, still not working.

Comment: If you are on Linux or OSX make sure the file is executable. It should go into one of the two directories listed in `Edit>Preferences>Folders>Plugins` (preferably the one in your home directory)

Comment: Ok, once I found the right folder, copied it there, AND made the file executable `chmod +x filename` (Linux) it worked !

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter to do the offset once (scroll and and put pixels exiting on the other side) - but no ready made filter to animate that.

To create the animation you'dhave to write a small script that will:

call "offset" on a layer, copy the result, paste as new layer (on the same or on a new image, containing only the animation).

In my answers here and on stackoverflow regarding GIMP there are some examples and instructions on how to that programaticaly.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A19151+python+is%3Aanswer
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A108205+is%3Aanswer+gimp+python

Comment: Instead of just providing links why not make your answer better and provide an example?  I would upvote this if you had an example.

Comment: time constraints. and repetition. The informatin is there - this is not a duplicate question, but I'd have to rewrite a lot to get an working example. If you do that, I will be pleased to upvote our answer.

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to solve the problem from this :-D

Comment: Ok. Don't misinterpret me, I'd really like to write down a more complete example as DarthVader suggests.

Comment: If you get time that would be great, but I'm pleased for your direction. Thanks.